# Viewing xml in chrome..?

Tags: google-chrome, xml

I used to open my xml files in chrome and read them as plain text (and it formatted it nicely and color coded it). I haven't had to dig through any xml files in months now. But now when I try to open one, it just loads my home page in chrome. Am I crazy? Did I used to not use chrome to do this and I just thought I did? Did I have some kind of extension that did this for me (doubtful)? I swear this is what I used to do but now it's not working and I'm at a loss as to what has changed..

So to be clear, my question isn't what extension can I use to give me this functionality, but rather whether or not Chrome has (or had) this built in or not.

Comment: Works for me. But it only shows the file contents when I use `view-source:`

Comment: How are you opening your file?   I just dragged and dropped an XML file to Chrome (had to be the address bar and not the browser pane) and it worked fine, as does loading a URL.